# How to find and modify source code for Magento Media Storage?

Tags: php, magento

I want to add a "load from URL" option to magento media storage, but I really don't have any idea how to do that as I cannot find the block of code that outputs the media storage.

- I tried using template hints but they are aimed at frontend not backend, so useless.
- I tried to find a file containing media/storage in the magento docs... nothing useful found.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to look in `Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php`, `Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Media/UploaderController.php` and `Mage/Media/Model/*`

Some advices if you are really new to magento :

1. Create a module to override core items (there are plenty of tutos over the net my prefered is the [inchoo's one](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/))
2. The architecture of adminhtml is specific and you'd better have a close look at it to moke it
3. The cache and compilation are strong enemies in module development so deactivate them if is not yet done

Comment: Thank you, you helped more than I expected!